# How can i set my html files with css in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i need your help.
I have profile page, i researched lots of websites, but i can't found, can you help me?
I need to center all all of the items, and my image has to be like ANGELA YU (image of the top, you can see).
Please help

```
 <div className="asd">
    <img alt="123" src={asd}></img>
      <div className="top-container">
        <div></div>
        <div className="user-profile-img">
          <img alt="profileImg" src={user.photoURL}></img>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="middle-container">
        <p>Your email: example@gmail.com</p>
        <p>Your user id: 123213213213</p>
        <p>Your display name: ASDSADASDSA</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Use `text-align: center` if you have `100%` width, otherwise use `margin: 0 auto;` or if you want to center both vertically and horizontally, use `flexbox` properties ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/11866037))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `text-align:center` to the classes that you want the text to be centered. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_center.asp) you can see how to center an image. Just google.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to create a common class `.textCenter{text-align:center}` and use it in the each parent `<div>` example `<div className="middle-container textCenter">` the all the child elements in this will be aligned center to that `<div>`.
2. If you want the name in 2 lines as you shown in the above sample image then you need to give max-width to the name tag example: `max-width:'50px'`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using **flexbox**.

You can wrap the content you want to center in a `div`, and apply this **CSS** to it :

```
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
```

Here is a [cool website](https://flexboxfroggy.com/#en) to learn flexbox.